# C# WPF Changing ContentControl Content based on DataTrigger not working

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger

I am trying, with no luck, to change the content of a content control based upon a DataTrigger, that checks a binding to see if it matches a type, and if it does change the `contentcontrols` displayed content.

In short, I want this ContentControl's Content to change if the Source is a certain type.  I have attempted to do this using Styles / DataTriggers

```
<ContentControl>
  <ContentControl.Content>
    <TextBlock Name="CollectionControlTextBox1" 
         Tag="." 
         PreviewMouseDown="CollectionControlDefaultDockPanel_MouseButtonDown"
         PreviewMouseUp="CollectionControlTextBox1_PreviewMouseUp"
         MouseMove="CollectionControlDefaultDockPanel_MouseMove"
         Drop="CollectionControlDefaultDockPanel_Drop"
         Foreground="{Binding Meta.ColorBrush, Mode=OneWay, TargetNullValue={StaticResource TextBrush}, FallbackValue={StaticResource TextBrush}}"
         AllowDrop="True"
         MinHeight="20" 
         Padding="5 2 0 0"
         KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False"
         Focusable="True"
         TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
         ContextMenu="{Binding ParentControl.MemberContextMenu, Mode=OneWay}"
         Text="{Binding DisplayName, Mode=OneWay}">
      <TextBlock.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static iugo:EditorCommands.Metadata}" Executed="Metadata" />
      </TextBlock.CommandBindings>
    </TextBlock>
  </ContentControl.Content>
  <ContentControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source, Converter={StaticResource IsAssociation}}" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding IdEntry.Id}" ToolTip="{Binding IdEntry.Entry.Name}" FontSize="10" Foreground="{StaticResource DisabledTextBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0, 3, 0, 0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding IdEntry.Entry.Name}" ToolTip="{Binding IdEntry.Entry.Name}" FontSize="13" Margin="5, 0, 0, 0"/>
              </StackPanel>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

I have tested that the converter: `IsAssociation` is correctly being hit, and is correctly the right value, but the Content does not change to a `stackpanel` as defined in the `DataTrigger`. I have confirmed this by using Visual Studios' Visual Tree, and it still links to the old content.

Comment: I think you don't need DataTrigger for that. You simply apply converter to the Text property. Then in the converter, you can check the type of the value, and then you can change the Text property according to that.

Comment: I would recommend you to use Custom Control for your purpose. I think that will full fill your need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A directly set `Content` like

```
<ContentControl>
    <Content>
        ...
    </Content>
</ContentControl>
```

has higher [value precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence?redirectedfrom=MSDN) than a value set by a Setter in a Style Trigger. Your DataTrigger is hence ignored.

Instead of directly setting the Content, move the initial value to another Setter:

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TextBlock ...>
                        ...
                    </TextBlock>
                </Setter.Value>
             </Setter>
             <Style.Triggers>
                 <DataTrigger ...>
                     <Setter Property="Content">
                         <Setter.Value>
                             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                 ...
                             </StackPanel>
                         </Setter.Value>
                     </Setter>
                 </DataTrigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```